# Meaning of "endgeilfett"

Tags: meaning

For example:

> Frü­her ein­mal fand ich Klas­sen­kampf **end­geil­fett**.

I suppose it is just a combination of *endgeil* meaning *awesome* (slang) and *fett* meaning *awesome* (slang), for superlative effect.  Is there any more to it than that?

Comment: Yeah, you're pretty much spot on. It really doesn't mean anything at all.

Comment: @Cubic: What do you mean with "doesn't mean anything at all". y7sg is right, it is just a combination of two adjectives to emphasize the meaning. If something is "endgeilfett", it is more awesome than if it was just "endgeil" or "fett".

Comment: Additionally, by using those two slang expressions in this combination, the author is making a stylistic choice. As he also expresses a change in his opinion, I believe he is making fun of his younger self for believing such preposterous things and using such cliché-ed language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. It's a composition of `endgeil` and `fett`, both of which mean `awesome`. The composition just increases the "awesomeness", but not in a superlative fashion. It can be even further increased by adding further adjectives meaning `awesome` to the composition

> supermegaendgeilfettkrass

Answer (score 2):

I just came over this Topic and remembered of a poster from the german "Duden" (15 years ago I think) were it says:

> geil -> affengeil -> oberaffengeil

to express the increase of the adjective

so if you want to express even more superlative then the normal just concatenate different words to express "awesomeness"

> oberaffenmegaüberfettgeil

(but that's more childish slang)

Comment: Now I understand what Bruce and Bongo said in their 80's hit "Geil" :-)