# What does "endgeil" mean in German?

Tags: translation, meaning, teen-slang

What does *endgeil* mean in German, is it comparable to *awesome* in English? Is there a direct translation of the word?

This is "teen slang" and therefore hard to find in many dictionaries.

Comment: Welcome to GLU.SE, translations are allowed in this site only in certain cases. Please read the guidelines [here](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/343/when-is-a-translation-request-to-german-off-topic). It seems your question might be answered by using a (free online) dictionary.

Comment: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/10106/1224 - http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/endgeil

Comment: This question is probably "almost" good enough for the site. To improve it, cite the translated English words that Duden spits out (there's a link in the above comment), and relate why you have trouble connecting those "teen slang" translations to "awesome."

Comment: Hint: There is a Brazilian Portuguese word, "bestial" that means "awesome. More to the point, it is "not far" from Duden's translations. That is a "link."

Answer (score 3):

*endgeil* translates as a comparative form of *geil*, thus meaning `very cool`.

so by some aid of the [urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=kewl), you might say `wicked kewl` or `hella kewl`.

don't forget that colloquialisms, especially from adolescent slang, tend to lose their wicked coolness pretty fast ... ;-)

Comment: And it should also be noted that some people find the use of the word “geil” offensive, since it can have sexual connotations. Just as “fucking great” can lead to raised eyebrows if used out of place.

Comment: @Kay, so would you use it in a talk?

Answer (score 2):

*endgeil* means great, very good, awesome. It is very colloquial.

I don't think that there is a direct translation as it is colloquial.

Answer (score 1):

"endgeil" würde ich als individuelle Wortschöpfung einer 14Jährigen ansehen und es dürfte wohl nur eine Eintagsfliege sein. Aber junge Leute lieben "gspinnerte" Ausdrücke in ihrer Clique.
Ich wäre sehr vorsichtig mit sochen Ausdrücken spezieller Cliquen. Die können woanders völlig unbekannt sein oder in einem halben Jahr schon wieder ein alter Hut sein.

Sorry, I wrote in German. I would see "endgeil" as an individual word creation of a fourteen-year-old  girl, and I think it's a flash in the pan. But youngsters love crazy expressions in their clique.
I would be careful in using such expressions of special cliques. Somewhere else they may be totally unknown or they may be old hat in half a year.

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/endgeil

Comment: Ich hab es noch nie gehört und werde es auch nie benützen.

Answer (score -6):

**geil --> horny** --> looking forward to something a lot

**end --> ultimately**

(This was) (making me) **ultimately** **horny**. 
--> Not directly

But.

> This was so pleasant or good as if I would have had sex. I'd even
>   prefer it to sex. I'm very **keen** (**horny**) to do this again.

Or in short.

> This is experience was so ultimately good, thus making me very keen to do it again.

Comment: “Horny” is just one meaning of “geil”.